# URL host name returns null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to get the hostname of a string url

I am trying to create the NSURL object from the string and then using host property of NSURL to get the host name. But Host name is always null.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.google.com"];
NSLog(@"Host name %@", url.host);
```

but the host name is always null.
can anybody explain why is host name null?

Edit: I am sorry there was a typo i missed a quote and a comma while asking the question. But the problem is still the same.

Comment: You also missed a comma in your NSLog

Comment: The problem is the missing http:// in the URL - see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html),

```
- (NSString *)host;
```

**Return Value:**

> The host of the URL. If the receiver does not conform to `RFC 1808`,
> returns nil

So if it is not conforming to `RFC 1808`, it will return nil. As per definition of [`RFC 1808`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808),

correct syntax is as follows :

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

So you need to add `http://` also while forming `NSURL`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSLog(@"Host name %@", url.host);
```

Comment: yes i guess i overlooked it. I was under impression, if the url object is not nil using the string without scheme the host name should also not be nil.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing a " after www.google.com? Try adding it in.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"www.google.com"];
NSLog(@"Host name %@", url.host);                  ^
                     ^
```

(Notice on the second line I also added a comma, I tried to point at it with a ^ best I could)

EDIT: Ah, okay then it may be the comma on the second line then.

Comment: Also take a look at what @ACB said, that may be your main problem and he is right regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This will work better if you do (add http://):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
NSLog(@"Host name %@", url.host);
```