# how to convert host of nsurl to lowercase

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsurlcomponents

Let's say I have www.GOOgle.com/.......

I want to change it to www.google.com/....

and keep the rest of url as it is.

I have tried with `NSURLComponents`, but it didn't work.

```
// I am taking input from textfield and making the nsurl.

 NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: _textfield.text]; // input from textfield
[[components host] lowercaseString];
 NSURL *urlin = [components URL]; //but this gives, www.GOOgle.com
```

Any lead is appreciated.

Comment: why not `[_textfield.text lowercaseString];`before convert to `NSURL`

Comment: Why you need to covert url to lower case ?

Comment: `[[components host] lowercaseString]` That's returning something, that doesn't modify it. It should be at least `[components setHost:[[components host] lowercaseString]];` Also, is `[components host]` nil, no? If you add `http://` to your string text, if may work then. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130315/url-host-name-returns-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Larme Suggests you can use method to setHost in url

see below example

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString: @"https://sTackoverFlow.com/questions/47924276/how-to-convert-host-of-nsurl-to-lowercase"]; 
[components setHost:[components.host lowercaseString] ]; 
NSLog(@"%@",components.URL)
```

> H
>   ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924276/how-to-convert-host-of-nsurl-to-lowercase

---

NOTE:

**http://** is required to add in String otherwise you will get host nil 
eg https://www.sTackoverFlow.com/questions/47924276/how-to-convert-host-of-nsurl-to-lowercase it will work

while

www.sTackoverFlow.com/questions/47924276/how-to-convert-host-of-nsurl-to-lowercase

### Will Not work

Answer (score 0):

If your string is only url then, you can try this,

```
let strURL = "http://GOogLe.Com/Testt/xyz"
let url = NSURL(string: strURL)
let domain: String = (url?.host)! //get your host name
print(domain) //GOogLe.Com

let str = strURL.replacingOccurrences(of: domain, with: domain.lowercased())
print(str) //http://google.com/Testt/xyz
```

Comment: Do not use `NSURL` in Swift. Use `URL`.

Comment: And this can fail since it is possible that the domain could be in the URL more than once but only the actual domain part of the URL should be changed.

Answer (score -1):

1. Convert the string to lowercase.
2. Then pass the converted string value to the componentsWithString method.

**Sample**:
 NSString *lowerCaseStringValue = [_textfield.text lowercaseString];
[NSURLComponents componentsWithString: lowerCaseStringValue];

Comment: This will convert the entire url to lowercase, which we do not want. Thanks for the time.